# How to implement login redirect and coming back in MvvM pattern?

Tags: c#, mvvm

A very specific question with regards to MvvM (no specific framework):

- UI has a login screen
- UI provides some action that requires the user to login

Say we have a list of things and clicking a thing should trigger a download.

- The click triggers a `Download()` method in the view model.
- The user clicks the third thing.
- The view model asks a service to download.
- The service replies "not authenticated".

The view model can now navigate to the login screen (or tell the UI to navigate there if we don't have view model navigation).

But how will the user **get back to exactly the action** that was triggered (restore the UI and start downloading the third thing) when the user has completed the login?

Are there standard patterns to solve such situations?

I feel like I'm thinking too complicated here...let's see if there will be answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You usually just pass a continuation to the authentication method. Think of how ASP.NET form authentication works with the return URL as a query string argument - this is what I mean by continuation. Some encoded instruction of how to resume.

For example: [PRISM has a navigation service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) that accepts URLS for moving between views or view models and could easily support an authentication step that worked in the same way as ASP.NET forms based authentication. I suggest reading through the link to see how it's implemented there and then you could use that (I've had good success in commercial projects) or something similar.